# How to import multiple mailboxes based on a CSV file?

Tags: powershell, csv, exchange-server, exchange-server-2013

I have a CSV file with 100+ lines in this format:

```
\\10.10.10.1\PSTs\DJ10001.pst,John.Doe@example.com
```

I want to loop through the file and import the PST file to the mailbox.

I understand that I can use Exchange Management Shell to import a PST to a mailbox:

```
New-MailboxImportRequest -FilePath \esp-ho-ex2010apstalan.reid.pst -Mailbox john.smith
```

However I'm not sure how to loop through a CSV file and use the values from it in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Import-Csv` cmdlet to import the CSV, iterate over each record using the `Foreach-Object` cmdlet and access the current record within the foreach loop using `$_`:

```
Import-Csv 'yourCsvPath.csv' -Header 'pst', 'email' | ForEach-Object {
    New-MailboxImportRequest -FilePath $_.pst -Mailbox $_.email
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll need to add a row `pst,email` to the top, right?

Comment: No, I assumed your csv doesn't contains a header thats why I provided it. If your CSV contains a header, you can omit the `-Header` parameter and use the header names instead when accessing `$_.`

Comment: Ah, sorry I should have read up on `-Header`, so that's exactly what I want, and I don't need to add the row. Great. Thanks